# "Made strong through the struggles"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

My family is from Germany, I don't know how to speak the language, although my grandfather was fluent. His favorite phrase was "Made strong through the struggles" and I believe it went something like "stark durch die Kämpfe". Just looking for the correct translation.

Comment: This isn't idiomatic, is it? So I guess we're looking for an almost literal translation and then your translation is fine.

Answer (score 3):

"Was uns nicht umbringt, macht uns stärker" (What doesn't kill us only makes us stronger) would be a similar quote by Nietzsche.

Comment: And i missed that one. Good catch.

Comment: You misquote slightly though. The original is "Was mich nicht umbringt, macht mich stärker." Nietzsche, Götzen-Dämmerung, Sprüche und Pfeile 8, cf. http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/gotzen-dammerung-6185/3

Answer (score 0):

If this is idiomatic, a saying in Germany is

> *Das Leben hat ihn hart gemacht*

this doesn't refer to battles but to (difficult) life in general as the hardening factor, but it's the only idiom that comes to mind.